# I can't find the problem in my code, do you see it?

Tags: lua

When I attempt to run this part of my code an error shows up and says that it expected a string but it got a function, I'm new to coding and I can't figure out what's wrong. here's the error,

```
lua: game:47: bad argument #1 to 'find' (string expected, got function)
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'find'
game:47: in main chunk
[string "<eval>"]:11: in main chunk
```

and here's the code

```
if (string.find(location,patternno2) ~= nul) then
        print(" You decide that you will live your life as a hermit, alone and isolated. GAME OVER")
        return
    end
    local patternyes2 = '^[yY][eE]?[sS]?$'
    if (string.find(location,patternyes2) ~= nul) then
        print(" Great! You leave for the land of Yore.")
        print("You arrive at the castle of the previously mentioned king.")
    end
```

here's where location is assigned value

```
print(" Do you go to the quest location")
    local location = io.read
```

Comment: the error is saying  that `location` is a `function` not a `string`. Can you show where is `location` assigned it's value? also it is `nil` not `nul`, `nul` will still be nil, in this case, so it would probably work but it is still incorrect.

Comment: yeah the post is edited

Comment: you're missing `()` after `io.read`, so `location` is assign the function `io.read` rather than a string value

Comment: thanks, I forget the () way too often